# Multiple submit form in one html form file

Tags: jquery, mysql, forms

Id like to ask some easy and cross platform code/structure I can use for this form:
I have a form that have 3 sections
1st section : Entering course information
2nd section: Entering participants information
3rd section: entering Corporate account information

Each section has a submit button that when clicked saves the data to mysql database
User can add unlimited set of data per section (except 3rd section).
Meaning I will create an add button per section that will display one set of data in a table row. When clicked another row is added. When they are done with the desired number of set of data. They will click the submit button and these sets of data will then be saved in database.

I dont know how to approach it properly. If I use one submit button for all the section, I thought, I need to create sets of table inside mysql that corresponds to the number of fields in my html form.
The problem would be, the number of sets of data per section will be limited only to the number of tables in my sql

Comment: (Note: Is this PHP?) I'm not quite sure what the question is you're asking. Do you mean you don't know more or less how to do a setup where they have one page with a form containing three "sections" (`fieldset`s in HTML), whereas the first two should accommodate adding one or more lines? And you're worried about the tables and how you'll add the "dynamically" created rows (on the form)?

Comment: see this : http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/multipart/

Comment: Sorry to confuse, what i mean to say is. I have this html form with three sections (grouped accdng to fieldset). In each section there has an add button. Mainly because I want to give the user ability to add more records in each section, everytime they hit add button a table is created inside that section listing all the record they have added. e.g. Section1: Add participants (they can add as many participants name they want). The form html and tables are all okay, my problem is how can I approach this in the database.

Comment: I have very little knowledge about Php, but I can connect fields to mysql tables using jquery, a little ajax and php code. My problem is how can i insert participants name to database (depending on how many of them are added in the form). My thought is I can only add one field in the database for name, but when use created 3 names, how can it be saved in the database with only 1 name field available.. I hope you will get what I mean.. Thanks a lot